# Personal Info to the Header to Save Space with Tight-space rules

Tags: header-footer, titles

My lecturer insists on extreme space-rules, max 2 pages, with quite advanced simulation problem (with all codes required to include). So I have to change my personal info to as small space as possible. I want to reuse the de facto things such as `\author{...}...\title{...}...\date{...}`. How can I do it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\maketitle
\title{Simulation Assignment 3. XYZ}
\date{\today}
\author{Student Number XYZY, XYZ University}

\begin{document}


\input{Documents/h3}
\verbatiminput{Codes/h3.r}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're still interested in using the traditional "personal info" commands (like `\author`, `\title` and `\date`), you only need to modify `\@maketitle`. `\@maketitle` takes information that is stored after calling the "personal info" commands and assembles them with specific header spacing and font selections. Here's the original definition:

```
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
```

Note all the `\vskip`s. Here's the output with your MWE (with the addition of [`showframe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe) to identify the page boundaries):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}% http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe
\title{Simulation Assignment 3. XYZ}
\date{\today}
\author{Student Number XYZY, XYZ University}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
​\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Here's a modified version with a shorter/smaller `\@maketitle`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}% http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe
\title{Simulation Assignment 3. XYZ}
\date{\today}
\author{Student Number XYZY, XYZ University}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
  \centering
  \let \footnote \thanks%
    {\normalsize \@title \par}
    {\small%
        \@author%
        \par
    {\small \@date}\par%
  }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\maketitle
​\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

The main difference is the removal of `\vskip`s and larger font sizes (reduced to `\normalsize` and `\small`). Of course, you can modify this to suit your requirements.

Answer (score 4):

You need `\title` etc to be before `\maketitle` so the information is stored up when the title is set, article then uses

```
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
```

so you can redefine that reducing the skips and replacing `\large` and etc by smaller fonts, or changing the layout altogether, depending on your requirements.